# Cannot write Data to file in Swift

Tags: swift

I have an image that I want it's data to be saved in this fileUri generated by ("react-native-fs"). LibraryDirectoryPath/saved_images/{filename}:

> /Users/macbookpro/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/9CBD2F1E-7330-418D-81BE-108C064DEA7E/data/Containers/Data/Application/C26348CC-3463-43EF-9B26-B7E31641E2EA/Library/saved_images/6B3A6A3A-8DE3-488B-AF43-A54775545B38.jpg

And below is my implementation:

```
do {
    let url = URL(string: fileUri)
    let fileExisted = FileManager().fileExists(atPath: url!.path)
    
    if (fileExisted) {
        try decryptedData.write(to: url!)
    } else {
        let handle = try FileHandle(forWritingTo: url!)
        handle.write(data) // data is type Data
        handle.closeFile()
    }
} catch {
    reject("FileError", "Failed to write file", error)
}
```

I also tried `let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: fileUri)`  with and without `file://` prepending to fileUri

```
do {
    let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: fileUri)
    let fileExisted = FileManager().fileExists(atPath: url.path)
    
    if (fileExisted) {
        try decryptedData.write(to: url)
    } else {
        let handle = try FileHandle(forWritingTo: url)
        handle.write(data)
        handle.closeFile()
    }
} catch {
    reject("FileError", "Failed to write file " + error.localizedDescription, error)
}
```

it says:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "can't seem to get the error"? How about `print(error)`?

Comment: I use react native to call native and js part cannot get the error and the debugging part does not work because I can only build the app in cmd

Comment: What is `fileUri`?

Comment: fileUri = /Users/macbookpro/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/9CBD2F1E-7330-418D-81BE-108C064DEA7E/data/Containers/Data/Application/C26348CC-3463-43EF-9B26-B7E31641E2EA/Library/saved_images/6B3A6A3A-8DE3-488B-AF43-A54775545B38.jpg

Comment: Show the code that generates the value that is in `fileUri`.

Comment: fileUri = this library ("react-native-fs").LibraryDirectoryPath/{filename}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong API.

```
let url = URL(string: fileUri)
```

is for strings representing a full – even encoded - URL starting with a scheme like `file://` or `https://`.

On the other hand `fileUri` is actually a path without a scheme, so you have to use

```
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: fileUri)
```

This returns a non optional URL by adding the `file://` scheme.

`fileUri` should be renamed as `filePath`.

Comment: I tried with and without`file://` prepending to fileUri it says the file doesn't exist. See updated

Comment: Where does the path come from? You have to determine the URL to the application container with `FileManager` every time you are going to access the sandbox. And you don't need `FileHandle` as `write(to` overwrites data.

Comment: Apart from the filename which is generated by me the other part generated from this library ("react-native-fs").LibraryDirectoryPath

Comment: You should not write user data directly into `Library`. Better write the data into `Documents`